# Problems accessing rootviewController of navcontroller iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Im working off the seismic xml iphone example.
In that example there is simply the application delegate which has a rootViewController of type UITableViewController.

I wanted to modify it slightly so that I would have a navigationController and use its rootViewController as the table view. My root view controller class for my navigation controller is named "firstLevelViewController"

In the sample code it says

```
 [rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

I want to say `[navController.firstLevelViewController.tableView reloadData]`

but I get errors saying "request for member firstLevelViewController in something is not a structure or union"

How can I reference the rootViewController of the navigationcontroller from the main app delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a `firstLevelViewController` property in a `UINavigationController`. If you want to access the current controller you can use

```
UITableViewController* firstLevelViewController = navController.topViewController;
assert([firstLevelViewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]);
[firstLevelViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

If `firstLevelViewController` means the view controller at the bottom you can use

```
UITableViewController* firstLevelViewController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
....
```

Comment: AH! Thankyou so much.

What I meant by "firstLevelViewController" was the default 1st root screen that the navigation control shows.
I read in a book that this always exists.

If I always want to refer to that firstLevelViewController that I'm on about would I use the objectAtIndex:0 method?

Comment: @dubbeat: Yes. But it may be more efficient to store the value in some properties of your App delegate or a static global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Access the rootViewController like this:

***Objective-C***

```
YourViewController *rootController =(YourViewController*)[[(YourAppDelegate*)
                               [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

**Swift**

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as YourViewController
```